# Chakra UI - Avatar component customization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to put an overlay over Avatar component image, but I can't figure out how to extend the theme properly.

What I've tried so far:

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react';
export const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Avatar: {
      parts: ['container', 'excessLabel', 'label']
      baseStyle: {
        excessLabel: {
          _before: {
           // overlay
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I tried to look at the theme [source](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/theme/src/components/avatar.ts) and figured it's a multipart component, but can't figure out how to target the src background image. And not sure about those parts either. Anyone, to enlighten me on how it should work?

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/media-and-icons/avatar

Comment: You could make a custom component instead, and put the avater and overlay both inside a `Box` with `relative` position, then place the overlay on top of the avatar

Comment: Did you use double quotes around the overlay content? Also, the excessLabel is the "+X" truncation for Avatar Groups. You may be wanting to add the overlay to 'container' instead.